# How to convert Platform^ string to wstring and then concatenate with a L string

Tags: c++

Take the following:

```
highestScore->Data( ) // wchar_t *Platform::String::Data     
startMenuItems.push_back( L"Highest score: " ); // startMenu is an array of wstring
```

How do I do the following?

```
startMenuItems.push_back( L"Highest score: " + highestScore->Data( ) );
```

I get the following error:

```
Error no operator "+" matches these operands
operand types are: const wchar_t[16] and const wchar_t*
```

It ends up getting used here:

```
virtual HRESULT CreateTextLayout(
  [in]   const WCHAR * string,
  UINT32  stringLength,
  IDWriteTextFormat * textFormat,
  FLOAT  maxWidth,
  FLOAT  maxHeight,
  [out]  IDWriteTextLayout ** textLayout
) = 0;
```

for the 1st parameter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
startMenuItems.push_back(
    std::wstring(L"Highest score: ") + highestScore->Data());
```

You need to `#include <string>`.